# ¿Cómo puedo buscar los pauses filtrados colocando en el input tanto mayúsculas como minúsculas?

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo una app sencilla de buscar los países del mundo trabajando con una API que me da toda la información de cada país, necesito que cuando busque en el `input` sea indiferente si se escribe con mayúscula o minúscula, por el momento solo me funciona con mayúscula usando `toLowerCase()`:

```
const getCountry = async () => {
  contries = await (
    await fetch('https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all', { method: 'GET' })
  ).json();
};
getCountry();
input.addEventListener('input', e => {
  const filtroPaises = contries.filter(filtro =>
    filtro.name.common.toLowerCase().startsWith(e.target.value)
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

acabo de probar esto y me funcionó:

```
$input = document.getElementById('input')

$input.addEventListener('input', e=>{
  if (!$input.value[1]) $input.value= $input.value.toUpperCase();
})
```

Fijate si te funciona